# Does $\int fdg=0$ for fixed positive $f$ imply $g$ is constant?

Tags: integration

The question formulated in the title is not very rigorous, so let me be more specific.

Assume that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb (0,\infty)$ is a given positive, continuous and strictly decreasing function, and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function of bounded variation with the property that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$
\int_x^y f(t)dg(t)=0
$$ 
for all $a\leq x<y\leq b$. Does this imply that $g$ is constant on $[a,b]$? If yes, are there any known references to results of this type?

Obviously the above implication is correct if $g$ is additionally assumed to be monotone (for instance by mean value theorem). So can it be assumed for a continuous function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ of bounded variation, the interval $[a,b]$ can be split into subintervals on which $g$ is monotone? (I know te example which shows that this is false if we drop continuity assumption.)

A little bit abstract formulation is for signed measures instead of function of bounded variation: assume that $\nu$ is a signed measure on Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ (non-atomic if necessary) and $f:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ is a continuous and decreasing function such that
$$
\int_{[x,y]}fd\nu=0
$$ 
for all $x<y$. (Equivalently, the integral $\int_B fd\nu=0$ for all Borel subsets $B$ of $\mathbb R$.) Can we claim that $\nu$ is a zero measure? (i.e. $\nu(A)=0$ for all Borel sets $A\subset\mathbb R$)

Comment: If $g$ is of bounded variation, then it can be written as the difference of two monotonically increasing functions.

Comment: @alex-r Yes, this is known as Jordan decomposition, but it doesn't help. For if $g$ is continuous and of bounded variation then $g=g_1-g_2$ where both $g_1$ and $g_2$ are increasing and they may be even chosen to be continuous. Now if $\int fdg=0$ over all subintervals of $[a,b]$, then $\int fdg_1=\int fdg_2$ but it doesn't mean that both integrals are zero. Also the Jordan decomposition says nothing about monotonicity properties of $g$.