# Integral hypothesis implies function constant a.s.

Tags: integration

Let $\mu$ a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f :\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $L^1(\mu)$.

Suppose that for all $\phi :\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded, measurable function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x)d\mu(x)=1$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d(\phi \mu)(x) \geq 0$, ie: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\phi(x) d\mu(x)\geq 0.$

The book I am reading says that considering $\pm \phi$ gives that $f(x)=c$ for some constant $c$ and for $\mu$-almost all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is : how is it possible ?

The only thing i can see is that $f=0$ $\mu$-a.s.

I've also found this : [Does $\int fdg=0$ for fixed positive $f$ imply $g$ is constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807565/does-int-fdg-0-for-fixed-positive-f-imply-g-is-constant) but it doesn't help.